# How can I use localStorage for storing clicks

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save the amount of clicks on a button in a textbox with localStorage, but whenever I reload the page, all the data is cleared. Here is my code:

```
var i = 0;  // i is the number of clicks. the number of clicks is set to 0 
when page is
// loaded.
function countClick() { // The next 3 lines of code are executed when the 
Kill a cat     // button is clicked
i++;

alert("You have clicked " + i + " cats so far"); // Make message box
localStorage.setItem("count", "i")
document.getElementById("count").value = i ; // Edits the 'clicks clicked' 
text box
// Saves number of clicks, so when you close      // or open the page, your 
progress still exists.

}
function clear() {
  document.getElementById("count").value = 0 ;
}

window.onload = function(){
  var val = localStorage.getItem('value'); // or localStorage.value

  if(val === null)
      val = "i";

 document.getElementById("myData").value = val;
}
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
localStorage.setItem('value', document.getElementById("myData").value);  
localStorage.value = document.getElementById("myData").value
}
```

Please help.

Thanks to all the other examples from the other people, used in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function, you reset your localStorage item before page load...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
localStorage.setItem('value', document.getElementById("myData").value);  
localStorage.value = document.getElementById("myData").value
}
```

It's normal there is no data when you refresh.
Just try somethink more simple like this without other function :

```
var i = 0;

function countClick() { 

i++;
localStorage.setItem("count", i)
document.getElementById("count").value = i ; 

}

window.onload = function(){
  var val = localStorage.getItem('count'); 

 document.getElementById("count").value = val;
}
```

Comment: I know its been a long time, but this really helped me. Thanks.